# Mobile App - Check if device is moving by accelerometer

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ionic2

I'm developing a mobile app with Ionic Framework 2, and using the plugin to get constantly the device accelerometer values in x,y,z. I would like to use that information to check if the device is moving, since the place where it's gonna be used is really small and the gps information oscillation wouldn't be precise. Since the accelerometer also has some oscillation, there would have to be some threshold, so it doesn't take that variation as a movement. Anyone did something like that and can give me some path for getting started? Looked for some implementation in that line and found nothing. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!